# Javascript event accessing when there is another parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I am working on a feature where if you click a blurb link, it will display the full description in a preview window; much like the search result preview in search engines, like Google.

I need to pass both the full description text and the event to the handling function so the function knows what to display and where to display (under the blurb).

My question is that what should I pass to the function. Currently I have below and it's not working:

```
<a href="javascript:DisplayFullDescription('blah blah description goes here');">blurb text here</a>

function javascript:DisplayFullDescription(e, fullText){
   //find out mouse click position
   //display a preview window (div) with description there

 }
```

Comment: Function should be defined just with `function DisplayFullDescription(...) {...}`, no need for word `javascript` there. ) And do you write it within `<script>` element?

Comment: Why not to store the variable 'blah blah description goes here' in an custom attribute of the html tag, and then overfload the onclick function with inside a 'var string = $(this).attr('myattrname');' ?

Comment: You also realize that even without the error @raina pointed out this will not work http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/mcNWS/ your arguments do not match up. the event argument is not passed in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be much easier to use jQuery to bind the event handlers, and an HTML5 `data-*` attribute to store the full text, rather than using `onclick` attributes.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" data-fulltext="blah blah description goes here">blurb text here</a>
```

jQuery/JavaScript:

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    DisplayFullDescription(e, $(this).data('fulltext'));
    e.preventDefault();
});

function DisplayFullDescription(e, fullText){
    //find out mouse click position
    //display a preview window (div) with description there
}
```

Comment: You don't have to pass the data around. You could clean this up more by doing this `$('a').click(DisplayFullDescription);`, remove the `fullText` param and in the function `$(this).data('fulltext')` will work now.

Comment: Thanks @rlemon. and thanks for the events link. that was really helpful!

Answer (score 2):

If you're not using HTML5, personally, I would create a hidden element for the full text with `display:none`, which I would assign as data to each applicable element, and use that info on `click`

```
<a class="clickable" href="#">blurb text here<span style="display:none">blah blah description goes here</span></a>

$('a.clickable').each(function() {
    $(this).data('fulltext',$(this).find('span').remove().text());
}).click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('body').append('<div>'+$(this).data('fulltext')+'</div>');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<a id="someID" href="#" data-fulltext="blah blah description goes here">blurb text here</a>
<script>
var element = document.getElementById('someID'); // grab the element by id. (simple for this demo)
element.onclick = DisplayFullDescription; // attach the event handler to the onclick function

function DisplayFullDescription(e) { // because we attached the handler above the Event is passed as the first argument to the function (handler) 
    var description = this.getAttribute('data-fulltext'); // 'this' now references the element in which the onclick was invoked. 
    alert(description);
}
</script>
```

You can try this above and see if it meets your needs.

Considerations:
- This does not need jQuery library to function (it would be overkill to use it for just this)
- This will work cross browser (old and modern)
- This has nothing to do with HTML5 (which is cool... but again, overkill and limiting)
- data-* can be accessed using getAttribute() and does not rely on the element.dataset being available.

However it would benefit you to read up a bit more on [Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event)

Comment: Good points under considerations. I'm already using jQuery anyway. otherwise this will definitely be my choice. thanks mate!